# screen & xterm: how to select text with the mouse in one only pane when window is divided vertically

Tags: gnu-screen, xterm, split, terminal-multiplexer

Interestingly enough, this has also been a `tmux` issue for some:
http://daemonforums.org/showthread.php?t=7311

But currently I am sticking to `screen`, and I'd like to know how I can make `screen` "behave" in that respect.

Selecting text with the **mouse** is no problem unless the line gets longer than the width of the pane. I've already tried to experiment with `:width`, with and without the `-w` option. (wrap is on, otherwise it will look like a mess (`:+wrap`))

Oh, and `:width` is VERY picky about the setting. If you set `width` too high, long lines will cause the *whole* terminal to shift back and forth (i. e. if your `bash` prompt is `user@host $` it will only display as `r@host $`), which looks extremely ugly.

Selecting a long line that splits up into several times the pane width will result in the following behavior:

- Selector (inverse) will display **beyond** the left pane, overlapping into the right pane. This looks buggy, to begin with. Selector too should wrap at the right border of the pane.
- Pasting the selection will sometimes cause a long line to be cut off at the first partial line, truncating the rest; and sometimes even try to add `|` (!), trying to continue the line as if it was a multiline *script* (result: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token '|'`) Argh.

Can't this be made work somehow even when using the mouse?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no, GNU screen cannot do this.

Long answer: GNU screen largely ignores the xterm mouse protocol, except for a special case where it accepts *mouse clicks* (the *"mousetrack"* feature).

To make selection work as you suggest would take a lot more work:

- The xterm mouse protocol works by making the terminal send escape sequences to your application.
- `screen` uses only the "normal" mouse protocol (1000), which sends an escape sequence when a mouse button is pressed, and another escape sequence when (any) mouse button is released.
- just clicks like that will not support the sort of dragging that you expect when selecting/pasting.  So `screen` doesn't try to do anything in that regard.
- when the xterm mouse protocol is active, you cannot do select/paste unless you use a <kbd>shift</kbd> mouse button.
- either way (whether you turn `mousetrack` on, or not), `screen` relies upon the terminal to show selection highlighting.  xterm (and other terminals) do not have a way to set selection-margins, so you get the full width of the screen highlighted.

In contrast, `tmux` does more with the mouse.  It actually translates between the different types of xterm mouse protocol to provide for differences between terminals, e.g., choosing between UTF-8 mode (1005) and SGR (1006).

In principle, `tmux` *could* be modified to also provide an enhanced select/paste as described in this question, because it *can* set the xterm mouse-mode to 1002 (cell motion mouse tracking), which would tell it where to paint its own highlighting.  I don't see it implemented in the source-code, so your link to *[How does tmux select contents only in one pane ?](http://daemonforums.org/showthread.php?t=7311)* seems still relevant.

The (keyboard) copy mode in `tmux`, for instance, seems unaware of panes.

There are drawbacks:

- it would be **slow**: much slower than copy mode because (a) there are more characters sent back from your terminal and (b) your expectations of performance using a mouse would be biased.  This would very noticeable if you didn't happen to be running on a local machine but via ssh.
- the selection would only be useful to `tmux`, e.g., usually wouldn't be copied to other windows in your X environment.

Further reading:

- [Mouse Tracking](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking) (XTerm Control Sequences)
- [Default Key Bindings](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings) (XTerm manual)
- [Windows and Panes](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#WINDOWS_AND_PANES) (tmux manual)